# Perl ssh connection and execute telnet connection

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet, router, cisco

I have multiple cisco routers configured with telnet access allowed from 5 specified hosts. Now I want to execute a perl script on one host which connects via ssh to the other hosts and checks if telnet to the router is possible.
I tried the system "ssh host" command but unfortunately with no joy. Could somebody help me please?

Many thanks in advance.

I tried the following but with no success. Some ideas?

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

$ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("linuxserver", user => "username", password => "password", master_stderr_discard => 1);
$command = "telnet routername";
@out = $ssh->capture({stdin_data => "routerpassword\n"}, $command);

print "@out\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Net::SSH2](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH2) to connect and forward a connection to the router using the [tcpip](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH2#tcpip_%28_host,_port_%5B,_shost,_sport_%5D_%29) method. Alternately you can use [Net::OpenSSH](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) (which only requires the [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) binaries) to do the same, see the information on [Tunnels](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH#Tunnels).

Comment: Sorry, but I´m a really new to perl. Do you have a small code example?

Comment: @Stefan: The documentation for both of those modules show examples of how to use them right at the top. Just click the links.